# How can I call this function?

Tags: class, swift, viewcontroller

I am so stuck right now, I have tried everything which seams logical to me to make this work but having no luck...

I got this in a separate swift file:

import Foundation
import UIKit

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    func background() {
        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300));
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"bg.jpg")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

I want to call it into a separate view controller file. The reason I am doing it like this is because then I can just call the background class in all my view controllers a and I don't have to do the same code in each one.

The ways I have tried calling it are:

`MyViewController.background()` - I get error `Missing parameter for #1 in call`

`background()` - I get error `Use of unresolved identifier 'background'`

`MyViewController()` - I don't get error but nothing happens.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me how I can call this function into my 'ViewDidLoad' part in the view controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Even if you could call the `background` method in MyViewController, this would still not accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, because when you call `background` in the "separate view controller file", the `self` in the `background` method would be the *other* view controller - and so you would be putting the UIImageView into the *other* view controller's view, not *this* view controller's view. If you want to be able to do the same thing separately in each view controller, you need to make the `background` method available internally in each of them.

The way to do that is to inject `background` through an extension *into UIViewController itself*, from which all your view controllers inherit:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func background() {
        var imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"bg.jpg")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Now *any* view controller in your app can just say `self.background()` (or simply `background()`) to call this method.